# Highlight a record in a grid on form open

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I'm currently running into an issue with the following situation:

I have a right click event which executes a static method "inventTransferOrder". In that I have the following code:

```
select firstOnly invTransLine
where invTransLine.TransferId == invTrans.TransferId
   && invTransLine.LineNum == invTransLineNum;

args.record(invTransLine);

new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(InventTransferOrder), MenuItemType::Display).run(args);
```

In the form's (**InventTransferOrders** which lays behind the menu item InventTransferOrder) init method I'm executing the following code:

```
InventTransferLine      invTransLine;
QueryBuildDataSource    qbds;
QueryBuildRange         qbr;
;

invTransLine = element.args().record();

qbds = InventTransferLine_Q.dataSourceTable(tableNum(InventTransferLine));
qbr = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(InventTransferLine, LineNum));
qbr.value(strFmt('%1', invTransLine.LineNum));
```

This is doing *exactly* what it's supposed to do: it filters the grid using the data source 'InventTransferLine' to the one record with the matching LineNum.

Contrary to this, I need to show *all* records (the InventTransferLine gets prefiltered to only show the lines for the InventTransfer record that's selected) **BUT** the one record with the matching LineNum should be *highlighted* so that a user could start working with that line immediately.

Could anyone help me out with this?

I have used the following code, but it (visually) does not do anything:

```
InventTransferLine_DS.findRecord(invTransLine);
InventTransferLine_DS.mark(true);
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot and kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a timing problem. Overwrite the `executeQuery` method of the `InventTransferLine` data source and put a breakpoint there. Also put a breakpoint in the `init` method where you wrote your modification. You will see that the breakpoint in `init` gets hit first and then the breakpoint in `executeQuery`. This means that `executeQuery` removes any selections and markings you have done previously.

If you put your modification in the `executeQuery` method after the `super()` call, your selection and marking should remain. Of course you do not want to execute this modification every time `executeQuery` gets called, so you will have to add some additional logic.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty simple and clear solution. I just moved the method and method call from form/init to datasource/executeQuery and it's working perfectly fine. TIL executeQuery deletes previous marking/selection. Thank you a lot!